# Do I need to quarantine at Fukuoka Airport after domestic travel?

Tags: japan, quarantine, fukuoka

I am going to travel to Fukuoka from Tokyo. Is quarantine needed at Fukuoka City?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, Japan does not have any restrictions on domestic travel.

Comment: Thank . I will accept your answer when I got Fukouka hotel :)

Comment: It might be worth nothing that the OP _will_ need to quarantine in Fukuoka if they are arriving from abroad. But after that, there are no more quarantines barring close contact, etc.

Comment: If they are arriving in Tokyo from abroad, they will need to quarantine in *Tokyo* before they will be allowed to utilize any public transit, including domestic flights (i.e. the Tokyo-Fukuoka flight.)

Comment: @Gene The OP specified that this is domestic travel.

Comment: @lambshaanxy The comment was in response to the previous comment which asserted that quarantine would be required in Fukuoka were it international travel; that is wrong and could get someone who saw the comment into trouble when they are barred from their domestic connection.